# I'm getting error 500 from the WhatsApp API even though it was working perfectly for a while, has anyone ever experienced this?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I have a problem, I have an application that sends messages on WhatsApp, as follows: https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/PHONE_ID/messages but for a few days now, I have not been able to make requests sending messages, always giving the following error:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#131000) Something went wrong",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 131000,
"error_data": {
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"details": "Something went wrong"
},
"fbtrace_id": "AAGM8FSdO8IY-SsuSt-V3kb"
}
}

Does anyone know what can it be?

I tried changing the token, calling other variants of the route, as indicated in the following documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages/, but I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also and finally found that my message was missing the receivers phone number. After correcting this everything works fine again.

BR, Hannu